# Cast raw bytes to any datatype

Tags: c++, c++17, reinterpret-cast

I'm worried if my implementation is unsafe or could be improved. Suppose I have an array of bytes (more specifically, `std::byte`); is casting an element's address to a void pointer and then to any datatype safe?

```cpp
template <typename To>
constexpr To *byte_cast(std::byte &From) {
  return static_cast<To *>(static_cast<void *>(&From));
}

// or rather
template <typename To>
constexpr To *byte_cast(std::byte *From) {
  return static_cast<To *>(static_cast<void *>(From));
}
```

I'm avoiding `reinterpret_cast` due to its unreliability. Do note that I want to the `T *` to keep same address of the byte it was cast from.

I do have in mind that the array might not fit the datatype, or maybe endianness might cause a problem, but both will be fixed after my question's answered.

Comment: `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(p))` is exactly equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)`, by definition.

Comment: Safe? Casting - yes. Dereferencing - iff there exists an object of type `To` at the address `&from` or if `To` is among the allowed aliasing types - `unsigned char`, `std::byte`, or `char`.

Comment: Your code simply 'hides' the fact that you are (ulitmately) casting from a low-alignment type (std::byte) to a potentially higher alignment type. Thus, you will still elicit the UB caused by breaking strict aliasing requirements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your paired `static_cast`s are exactly equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`. Both cause UB due to strict aliasing violations (except when the target type is `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte`).

The solution is [`std::bitcast<T>(source)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast). It has the interface similar to what you attempted, except that it returns by value. It's not possible to have a "safe `reinterpret_cast`" that would return a pointer/reference.

A less modern alternative is `std::memcpy`.

Comment: Is it possible for the std::memcpy alternative to have a T* that points to the address of the byte?

Comment: @PhoenixCausesOof No. As I said, there's no way to make a "safe `reinterpret_cast`". You can only make a copy of the bytes with the desired type.

Comment: @Phoenix - Note that compilers know enough about `memcpy` and `bitcast` to be able to use a register as the target if `To` is small enough. It doesn't *have* to store the result to memory if it is just used in a computation.

Comment: How would I do the opposite operation? (convert a T* to a byte array)

Comment: @PhoenixCausesOof Casting  to `unsigned char*`, `std::byte*`, and `char*` is always safe.